# FontAwesome; Not working

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-4

This should be simple. I just want to display the font-awesome remove font, and the font awesome fa-camera-retro font. What on earth am I doing wrong. I made sure I am using the right class; I examined the website and just simply downloaded the CDN.

Copy this file to your hard drive and call it Index.html;
Examine this through ANY browser; It will not work. Somehow it works on Fiddle! WTF?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script> </script>

    </head>
<body>
WHY DOESNT THIS WORK = Remove It - <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> Heading 1 </th>
                            <th> Heading 2 </th>
                            <th> Remove </th>
                            <th> Icon 2 </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Element 1 </td>
                            <td> Element 2 </td>
                            <td>WHY DOESNT THIS WORK = <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></td>
                            <td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't get it; It doesn't work in my browser. I am using Linux Mint with Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It works; I needed the href=http://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **https:** (6th line)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script> </script>

    </head>
<body>
WHY DOESNT THIS WORK = Remove It - <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> Heading 1 </th>
                            <th> Heading 2 </th>
                            <th> Remove </th>
                            <th> Icon 2 </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Element 1 </td>
                            <td> Element 2 </td>
                            <td>WHY DOESNT THIS WORK = <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></td>
                            <td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```